# Solving $S=((sec*75)+f).*588, 1sec = 75f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's an easy one. I just can't think straight tonight. If I have $$S=((sec*75)+f)*588$$
What are the two equations I need to solve for $sec$ and to solve for $f$ ?
Also, $1sec = 75f$?

Comment: Divide both sides by 588 to get $\frac{1}{588}S=75sec+f$. Replace $sec$ with $75f$, then divide both sides by $75^2+1$ to get $f$, and multiply that answer by $75$ for $sec$. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: You already have two equations. Replace the $sec$ in your first with what it's equal to; that is, $75f$.

Comment: @anon Yes... Thats what I was after. Thanks. Can you put it in an answer so I can close it? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=588(75sec+f)$$
$$\frac{1}{588}S=75sec+f$$
Replace $sec$ with $75f$,
$$\frac{1}{588}S=75(75f)+f=(75^2+1)f$$
$$\frac{S}{588(75^2+1)}=f$$
and multiply the above by 75 for $sec$. It's possible (seeing the two 75s paired together) there was an error made before the given question was posed but I'll leave that up to you OP.